# Omnisharp server is not running Windows 10

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code to try out ASP.NET a little bit, but when I try to do: 
    dnu restore
it fails.

If I try to do it within VS Code I get a error message:
    Omnisharp server not running.

I don't really know what to do :(
I'm running Windows 10 x64

Comment: I did a basic web search for "start omnisharp server" and it was answered on the first result I clicked. Did you do any research? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes? I only could find things for OSX

Comment: Did you try looking at the Omnisharp repository on GitHub to see what their documentation says?

Comment: I couldn't find anything regarding Windows to start the server.

Comment: There's a heading "Windows" in big bold letters, and below that it says "To start the Omnisharp server manually" and then it describes how to do it.

Comment: I know, but it's a manual start. But I believe omnisharp is bundled with VS Code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check the vs code Omnisharp log, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>.

The `Omnisharp server is not running` error can result from a problem in your `project.json` causing issues with `dnu restore`. e.g. Issues resolving packages for one of the target frameworks?

It probably will not help but, you can try restarting Omnisharp : <kbd>F1</kbd> "omni restart"

C# support is not bundled but it does sound like you have successfully installed it. Otherwise add C# with <kbd>F1</kbd> "ext install", <kbd>Enter</kbd>, "C#"

You are right that there is little documentation

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp - introduction to project types and omnisharp
- <s>https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet.html - yes OSX because windows instructions are for Visual Studio</s> (page no longer available)
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/03/10/experimental-net-core-debugging-in-vs-code/ - expect better soon

Answer (score 21):

Tried almost everything (resetting settings, reinstalling VS Code) to no avail. Finally I've downgraded VS Code C# extension from 1.25.0 to 1.24.4, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: How to downgrade VS Code C# extension?

Comment: @WasiqulIslam right click on the extension in the market place and click something like "Install specific version"

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio Code has Omnisharp built in. However, that doesn't mean you don't have to install ASP.NET 5 and DNX.

Follow the instructions found on this guide: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/runtimes/ASPnet5

Specifically, you'll want to follow these instructions: https://github.com/aspnet/home#upgrading-dnvm-or-running-without-visual-studio

Remember, Visual Studio is the heavyweight IDE that installs all that you need. Visual Studio Code is the lightweight node based editor that only has what you explicitly install/add to it. Thus, unlike Visual Studio, it does not automagically download ASP.NET 5 and DNX

Answer (score 3):

Another potential solution for folks in 2022 and later (**IF** the world is still here) -

1. Open VSCode Preferences --> Settings
2. Search "Use Modern Net"
3. Disable "Omnisharp: Use Modern Net"
4. Restart VSCode
5. (Optional) Check "Output" window (select C# or Omnisharp)
6. Great Success (and/or soul-crushing disappointment)

Read the settings tooltip on that "Use Modern Net" option and see if it applies to your case. If you're using some versions >= than what this setting is for, you may have some other thing going on... In which case, I would recommend looking in that "Output" window at the bottom of VSCode and selecting C# and/or Omnisharp to see what errors it throws for debugging purposes. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I solve this following this steps:

1. Goto VSCODE -> File -> Preferences -> Settings
2. Type "omnisharp" in the search toolbox
3. Disable the "Omnisharp: Auto Start" checkbox
4. Restart VSCODE
5. Type ctrl + shift + p to show the command textbox and look for
   "Omnisharp: restart omnisharp"

Now you can use ".Net: Generate assets for build and debug"

Comment: Thanks! I only need to select "OmniSharp: Restart OmniSharp" in the Command Palette.

Answer (score 1):

I completely uninstalled the C# extension. Reinstalled it and change the Omnisharp timeout to 15 seconds (initially was 60). Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I installed .NET SDK latest, and restart VScode. I were resolved problem. I so hope with you

Answer (score 1):

Most of the new omnisharp server problems are originated from your outdated dotnet version. I upgraded from .NET 5 to .NET 6.0, now it rocks!

Check your current version by writing "dotnet --version" to your terminal.
And download the .NET 6 from the following [link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download)

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was solved after installing the latest .NET SDK (6.0).

I got a more detailed error message after installing the .NET Extension Pack (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-pack).

Answer (score 0):

Click f1 key or ctrl+shift+p to open the textbox to enter your command. Then type omnisharp server, and select the option 'Restart omnisharp server'.

You can look at its status in the bottom left corner of the window, and if you click on it, the process's  status will on be displayed on the terminal.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem when I opened the .cs file separately, but then I right-clicked the project folder and chose "Open with VSCode" and it worked fine